# How to add delay to a placback in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, playback, audiotrack, audiorecord

The idea: I am trying to do an application like speech jammers. In theory when you listen yourself with a delay, you cant be able to speak properly.

So i am recording input from mic then playing it back to earphones. So far so good.

I want to add some delay to playback part. Looking for solutions.

```
 val audioRecord = AudioRecord(
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            intRecordSampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            intBufferSize
        )

         audioTrack = AudioTrack(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            intRecordSampleRate,
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            intBufferSize,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM,
        )

        audioTrack.playbackRate = intRecordSampleRate
        audioRecord.startRecording()
        audioTrack.play()

        while (isActive){
            audioRecord.read(shortAudioData, 0, shortAudioData.size)
            shortAudioList.add(shortAudioData)
            audioTrack.write(shortAudioData, 0, shortAudioData.size)
        }
```

-I have tried to start playing with a delay. Plackback started with a delay but couldnt played back my voice which i speak before audioTrack.play()

-I tried to save shortAudioData to arraylist and write it one by one to audioTrack. couldnt be able to.

To be clear, i want to start recording, after about 500 ms delay, i want to start playing it back till user clicks stop button.

Comment: Have you tried changing the buffer size of your `AudioTrack` to *0.5 * bitrate*? I don't know how it's handled in Android but generally that should add some delay, since it's like a longer conveyor belt between sound goes in and sound comes out. If that doesn't work, you could create your own buffer - you're filling `shortAudioData` and then dumping the whole thing into `audioTrack`, right? Instead of doing that, you'd have a much larger one, start filling from the beginning, but skip *reading from it* for however many iterations - so when you do start reading from the beginning, it's delayed